# How to set an interface for chain(YES/NO) logic?

Tags: gui-design, interface

I want to make an interface that will allow you to set a chain of events (namely races) using dependencies. Each race can have a YES/NO case (according to whether such a race took place or not) and no YES/NO cases at all. I attached a screenshot of the logic of such races. It is also worth considering that there can be countless such races. Perhaps someone will have interesting ideas for implementing such a sequence using a clear interface. It can be only for desktop.

P.S. This is my first request on UXstackexchange, if you need more information, feel free to drop a line
[image]

Comment: "...set a chain of events ... each...have a YES/NO case...[or] no...case...at all..." and "...implementing such a sequence..." please elaborate. What exactly is the user doing? I understand "add a race" and "possibly chain to other races with either yes or no." But where do the races come from? Is there an already existing list the user selects from? Or does the user make them up or have some source not associated with the app? Is there other information and/or criteria the user has to consider when making the assignments?

Comment: Hello! The races was created earlier. When the user sets up the chain, he will receive a list of races. The user must be able to make chain with any other chain part in current chain

Comment: What type of controls are you considering? Drag and drop? Or form elements, such as select lists, a couple containing the races, and maybe a yes/no radio button?

Comment: Do you mean races in the F1/100m/marathon sense, or in the orcs/elfs/dwarves sense? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Drag and Drop**

Drag and dropping graphic representations of the races from a "bin" of the race icons seems intuitive. — Drag a race to the page and drop it. It goes to the top. Drag another race over the race on the page and a couple "hotspots" pop up, one "yes" the other "no". When the new race is dropped on a hotspot it gets added to the chain in the chosen direction. A race can also be dragged off the chain to remove it. Broken links will need to be handled somehow.

**Select Lists**

Alternatively, a simple form can be used to chain races together.

There's two race select lists with a yes/no radio button pair between them, followed by a "LINK" button.

[image: begin]

Select "Race #1", "yes", "Race #7", and click "LINK":

[image: #7]

Select "no", "Race #11", and click "LINK":

[image: #11]

Comment: Ty, man! Unfortunately, I don`t have an opportunity to create graphic interface. Just simple elements like selectors/radio buttons/inputs, etc. But your left side with inputs and radio is really cool!

Comment: I made this task with table with 3 columns(Race ID/Child YES/ Child NO), which will be pasted in parser with different validations